# How to replicate every element of a column a for all elements of a column b?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with the following columns:

Month: string

Name: string

Count: number.

I'd like to take the month column and replicate all names in the different months in order to know where the count was 0 because in the data set if a name has no count, the date is not recorded.

reproducible example:

```
test <- data.frame(month = c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","Jan","Mar","Apr"), name = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B"), count = c(1,4,5,7,3,2,5))

# Desired result

testresult <- data.frame(month = c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr"), name = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B"), count = c(1,4,5,7,3,0,2,5))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `expand.grid` with `merge`

```
 merge(expand.grid(lapply(test[1:2], unique)), test, all.x=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# this may do what you want
# Create intermediate date frame with NA in missing counts
t1 <- reshape(test, idvar = "month", timevar = "name", direction = "wide")
# Create result data frame with original formats, and NA's included
testresult <- 
   reshape(t1, idvar = "month", timevar = "name", direction = "long")
```